# embedded jetty 9 classNotFound for AnnotationConfiguration in WebAppContext.doStart

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, war, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to setup an embedded jetty 9 instance which picks up annotations from a .war file.

So far it succeeds in running e.g. GeoServer.war (by setting ExtractWars to True), but I get a *ClassNotFound* on the *AnnotationsConfiguration* class when it picks up the WebChat.war which contains an annotated servlet.

In the example war, i added *'metadata-complete="false"'* to its web.xml, Also i added the next bit to the jetty server

```
  ContextHandlerCollection mHandlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();

  String mWebAppDir = ... ;
  WebAppProvider mAppProvider = new WebAppProvider();
  mAppProvider.setMonitoredDirName( mWebAppDir );
  mAppProvider.setDefaultsDescriptor( null );
  mAppProvider.setScanInterval(0);
  mAppProvider.setExtractWars(true);
  mAppProvider.setConfigurationClasses( new String[]{
    AnnotationConfiguration.class.toString(),
    WebInfConfiguration.class.toString(),
    PlusConfiguration.class.toString(),
    FragmentConfiguration.class.toString(),            
  });

  DeploymentManager mDeployMgr = new DeploymentManager();    
  mDeployMgr.addAppProvider( mAppProvider );
  mDeployMgr.setContexts( mHandlers );    

  /* Setup & Run server */
  mServer.addBean(mDeployMgr);
  mServer.setHandler(mHandlers);
  mServer.start();
```

I added all Jetty9 jars (jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506), including the jar 'websocket-core-9.0.0.M2.jar' to the jetty server project. The IDE knows *AnnotationConfiguration* class, but when jetty processes the war file, it comes with:

```
2013-07-16 14:05:36.731:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.3.v20130506
2013-07-16 14:05:36.753:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: 
 Deployment monitor [file:/C:/..../webapps/] at interval 0
2013-07-16 12:57:38.542:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main:  
 Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3ac8e6{/WebChat,null,null}  
 {C:\....\webapps\WebChat.war}

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
```

The *WebChat.war* contents is as follows:

```
\chat.html
\css\style.css
\js\jquery-1.3.2.js
\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
\WEB-INF\classes
\WEB-INF\lib
\WEB-INF\web.xml
\WEB-INF\classes\jettytest
\WEB-INF\classes\jettytest\Feature.class
\WEB-INF\classes\jettytest\FeatureWebSocket.class
\WEB-INF\classes\jettytest\FeatureWebSocketServlet.class
\WEB-INF\lib\websocket-api-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
\WEB-INF\lib\websocket-common-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
\WEB-INF\lib\websocket-core-9.0.0.M2.jar
\WEB-INF\lib\websocket-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
\WEB-INF\lib\websocket-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
```

Hoping to get a clue how to solve the classloading issue..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for viewing my question.

I found the problem;

I was running the jetty server *only* on port 8443, not on 8080. But the webchat.html file initialized using

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
      ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8443/WebChat/map");
```

But it should be the WSS protocol, since it's secure via 8443. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
      ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/WebChat/map");
```

Turns out it works WITHOUT setting the *setConfigurationClasses* as

```
  mAppProvider.setConfigurationClasses( new String[]{
    AnnotationConfiguration.class.toString(),
    WebInfConfiguration.class.toString(),
    PlusConfiguration.class.toString(),
    FragmentConfiguration.class.toString(),            
  });
```

Hope someone is helped with this.